# Java screen how to make the input line always be below

Tags: java

My problem is:
When i scan for user input in this method

```
public static void listenForCommand() {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    final Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(">");
    final String line = s.nextLine();

    String[] args = new String[line.split(" ").length-1];
    for (int i = 1; i < line.split(" ").length; i++)
        args[i-1] = line.split(" ")[i];

    commandEntered(line.split(" ")[0], args);
}
```

then there is "> "
but if something gets printed or logged then it looks like this 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL3bK.jpg (i cant use Image format because it says: "You need at least 10 reputation to post images." and i dont have 10 repuation.)

So how do i fix this? Are there some apis or libraries for this? I want that it looks like spigot or bukkit.

My Command Listener Class:
When the console gets input, it will split the first word in to the command and everything else are the args. Then it asks for every registered command in the main if there is a command registered with entered commandname.

```
package at.gebes.utils.command;

import java.util.Scanner;

import at.gebes.bot.Bot;

public final class CommandListener {

public static String[] commandNames = new String[1000];
public static String[] commandDescriptions = new String[1000];
private static CommandExecutor[] CommandClasses = new CommandExecutor[1000];
public static int counter = -1;

public static void registerCommand(final String CommandName, final String CommandDescription, final CommandExecutor CommandClass) {

    counter++;
    commandNames[counter] = (CommandName);
    commandDescriptions[counter] = (CommandDescription);
    CommandClasses[counter] = CommandClass;

}

public static void listenForCommand() {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    final Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(">\n");
    final String line = s.nextLine();
    //final String line = System.console().readLine();

    String[] args = new String[line.split(" ").length-1];
    for (int i = 1; i < line.split(" ").length; i++)
        args[i-1] = line.split(" ")[i];

    commandEntered(line.split(" ")[0], args);
}

public static void commandEntered(final String cmd, final String[] args) {

    if (counter < 0) {
        return;
    }

    boolean commandExists = false;
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {

            if (commandNames[i].equalsIgnoreCase(cmd)) {
                CommandClasses[i].onCommand(commandNames[i], args);
                commandExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!commandExists) {
        Bot.getLogger().info("Unknown Command. Try \"help\" for a list of commands.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is `commandEntered` and where do you print `help` or anything other than `>`?  Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Change `System.out.print(">");` to this `System.out.println(">");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you have to take record of current screen in any `String` type variable and then have to clear screen every time user inputs, then show the recorded screen and then the input line...

I think you got my point.

Comment: I tried but:
1. The line isnt always below
2. If a message or exceptions get printet after a time, it will still look like this

Comment: @Gebes, then add `\n` after the message which get printed, then the problem will be gone

Comment: i just want that the input line is always the belowest line. If something new gets printed it should be above the input line

Comment: @Gebes, in that case you have to take record of current screen in a String variable and then clear screen everytime user inputs then show the recorded screen and then the input line... I think you got my point